# Is "sendmail service" necessary for sending emails with Apache Commons Email Component which works throgh Java Mail API (javax.mail.jar)?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sendmail, apache-commons

My Java Web Application (running on Tomcat 7 in Jelastic Cloud) is sending emails using *Apache Commons [Email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html) Component*. This component is built on top of the *Java Mail API (javax.mail.jar)*.

Cloud hoster (Jelastic) says that ***"sendmail service is not running/available"*** (in case you do not purchase IPv4 for hosting - I do not need it, my application just parses certain web sites and sends parsing results to email - no GUI (http request/webpage), on deployment ServletContextListener starts Quartz timer which then runs forever.

Is this "sendmail service" vital/necessary for my emails to be sent/received correctly?

Jelastic support did not answer this question.

So far email works, but during trial sendmail service is not disabled - this "sendmail service is not running/available" applies after trial period, and now as my trial is going, it works but maybe just because sendmail service is not stopped during trial.

**Is sendmail service necessary for sending emails with Apache Commons Email Component which works throgh Java Mail API (javax.mail.jar)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to a mail server that supports the SMTP protocol.  sendmail is one such server.  You can also used hosted mail services such as Gmail.

Comment: So if I use it like this:  Email email = new SimpleEmail();  email.setHostName("smtp.mail.ru"); email.setSmtpPort(465);  - I use smtp server of the company where I have my email box registered (mail.ru - it is like gmail) and I do not rely on Linux sendmail daemon/service (Linux - is what cloud host runs as base for additional Tomcat and other java-hosting stuff), right?